# How to auto retry deployments to agents when they come online again (after having been offline)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When using Azure pipelines and deployment groups it is possible to re-deploy the "last successful" release to new agents with given "tags" using the instructions found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#automatically-deploy-to-new-targets-in-a-deployment-group

My issue is when releasing to a deployment group consisting of 3 machines. 2 are online and 1 is periodically offline. In this situation my release fails when the 1 machine is offline. This would be OK by me if Azure pipelines retried the deployment when machine offline comes back online. I thought this would work in the same way as "new targets", but I still haven't figured out how.

This is just a small test. When going in production my deployment group will consist of hundreds of machines and not all of them will be online at the same time.

So - Is it possible to automate the process to ensure all machines eventually will be up to date when all of them have been online?

Octopus-deploy seems to have this feature

- https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/9351-possibility-to-deploy-when-agent-become-online
- https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-patterns/elastic-and-transient-environments/deploying-to-transient-targets

**Status after failed deployment**
(and target is online again)

[image: Status after failed deployment]

Comment: Seems the feature isn't deployed to all the environment. I cannot see the feature with my account. However,in general the queued deployments will automatically triggered once the agent in online just like the build queues.

Comment: The "deploy on new target registered" works perfectly. First I register a onprem linux host in my deployment group and deploys. Target updated. I then register a second linux host as a new target in the same group. Seconds afterwards this host is updated and in the "log view" I can se "Deployment attempt #2" listed with my second target as the machine deployed to. Just as I would expect.

If I however try to deploy to a deployment group with 1 offline target and 1 online target the deployment fails. The offline target is not updated after coming online again

Comment: Well, in general the queued deployments will be automatically triggered once the agent is online. But for the failed deployments you have to re-deploy them manually.  No any way to retry it automatically when the agent is online again...

Comment: Ok - Are there any recommended way to manually redeploy to all "not-updated-agents"? For example using the API? When using the "redeploy-button" in the portal the deployment is redeployed to all targets online.

Comment: Have registered a ticket under Azure Devops explaining the situation:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/340920/redeploy-to-outdated-agent-when-it-comes-online-ag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in general the queued deployments will be automatically triggered once the agent is online. But for the failed deployments you have to re-deploy them manually. No any way to retry it automatically when the agent is online again...

Based on my test, to redeploy to all "not-updated-agents", you have to remove the other target machines which passed in previous deployment from deployment group...